# CKeditor adding an extra <br/> tag when a <br/> tag is encountered

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am experiencing a very annoying problem with ckeditor 4.4.7.3. Everytime a `<br/>` is entered into the editor, it displays the next line right below the existing line as one would expect. However, when you view the page, an extra `<br/>` tag appears along side the original `<br/>` tag. You can see this when looking at the source for the page.

```
Rendered output
<p>
  <strong>Age</strong>
  <br>
  <br>
  24
</p>
```

Looking at the source html while in ckeditor reveals that there is only one `<br/>` there.

```
Source as seen in ckeditor
<p>
  <strong>Age</strong>
  <br>
  24
</p>
```

This would seem to indicate to me that Drupal is adding line breaks while rendering the output. I have tried disabling the option: Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br>` and `<p>`) in the text format, but that doesn't change anything. I have also disabled JavaScript to see if some JavaScript file is doing this - but that makes no difference either.

I have googled this issue and have not found a solution yet (other people have been experiencing as well but no solution given). I would appreciate any suggestions in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, disabling the option: Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br>` and `<p>`) in the text format does make a difference. I needed to flush the cache to see the results. Hopefully this will help other people who experience this problem.