# How do I stop automatic double break tags in ckeditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

After updating the ckeditor module i find that saving existing content results in adding another break tag following existing break tags. When i create new content and press enter and save the final result has an additional break tags.

This is what i should be seeing according to the source button on the editor:

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The five boxing wizards jump quickly.<br>
Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.<br>
<br>
This is a second paragraphs made with two line breaks. Lets see if the editor decides to use two break tags or 4 break tags. These should also be enclosed with a paragraph tag instead of separated by two break tags.<br>
<br>
<br>
This third paragraph is now being separated by three break tags. Lets see if the editor decides to make this as size break tags instead of just three break tags. This Should be wrapped around a paragraph but also have a break tag above it.</p>
```

However what i see when i save the page ends up being:

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The five boxing wizards jump quickly.<br><br>
Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.<br><br><br><br>
This is a second paragraphs made with two line breaks. Lets see if the editor decides to use two break tags or 4 break tags. These should also be enclosed with a paragraph tag instead of separated by two break tags.<br><br><br><br><br><br>
This third paragraph is now being separated by three break tags. Lets see if the editor decides to make this as size break tags instead of just three break tags. This Should be wrapped around a paragraph but also have a break tag above it.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this post helped me out:
[CKeditor adding an extra <br/> tag when a <br/> tag is encountered](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155593/ckeditor-adding-an-extra-br-tag-when-a-br-tag-is-encountered)

basically go into
administration > configuration > content authoring > text formats.

then select the text format that's causing problems and unselect "convert line breaks into html" and save configuration.

Then clear all caches on Drupal and browser. The content should go back to normal just by visiting the page while you are signed in otherwise saving over it should fix the problem.